# SQL, need to show value rows wise

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

I have value in this format in database, I need to show these value rows wise, How can I do it?

I need to write down sql query for the same to show all the values row wise using sql query only.

| S.No | State Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Texas |
| 2 | Calofornia |

Comment: Where does column a come from what is column b - the first , last or some other part of the csv in the image? Are you generating a row for each token in  the csv?

Comment: we don't have any relation with any other table, It is just simple table in DATABASE, I need to get value row wise from the column. Actually as per the screenshot multiple value in the single column is the state name of US.

Comment: So the output would only be however many distinct states there are over all the csv ie a max of 50 rows (50 being the number of states in the us)? You could cut this down to a managable sample for clarity and publish as text.

Comment: yes, I need to show data row wise like s.no and then state name

Comment: in php we can use foreach loop to print the data from the value column one by one, that thing how can we do in sql

Answer (score 0):

Because the real table and column names are unclear, I'll give a more abstract answer.

There's some column containing values which are separated by a comma (or any other separator), thus forming a list of values. Having list semantics, the contents of the columns can be defined recursively as a list is

- either empty,
- consists of a single value
- consists of a single value that we call the head and a list that we call the tail while head and tail being separated by a comma (separator).

Because of this recursive definition, we can use a recursive CTE to split the string into head and tail using the functions locate() and substring().

```
WITH RECURSIVE list(head, tail) AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN locate(',', coalesce(txt, '')) > 0
                THEN substring(txt, 1, locate(',', txt) - 1)
                ELSE txt
           END,                                              -- head
           CASE WHEN locate(',', coalesce(txt, '')) > 0
                THEN substring(txt, locate(',', txt) + 1)
                ELSE NULL
           END                                               -- tail
      FROM (SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' AS txt  -- use
            UNION ALL                  -- your
            SELECT 'm,n,o') some_data  -- table instead
     WHERE coalesce(txt, '') <> ''
    UNION
    SELECT CASE WHEN locate(',', tail) > 0
                THEN substring(tail, 1, locate(',', tail) - 1)
                ELSE tail
           END,
           CASE WHEN locate(',', tail) > 0
                THEN substring(tail, locate(',', tail) + 1)
                ELSE null
           END
      FROM list
     WHERE tail IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM list;
```

results in

| head | tail |
| --- | --- |
| a | b,c,d,e |
| m | n,o |
| b | c,d,e |
| n | o |
| c | d,e |
| o | NULL |
| d | e |
| e | NULL |

We can now use this CTE as a subquery to get the desired result:

```
SELECT row_number() over () as pos, head FROM (
  WITH RECURSIVE list(head, tail) AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN locate(',', coalesce(txt, '')) > 0
                THEN substring(txt, 1, locate(',', txt) - 1)
                ELSE txt
           END,                                              -- head
           CASE WHEN locate(',', coalesce(txt, '')) > 0
                THEN substring(txt, locate(',', txt) + 1)
                ELSE NULL
           END                                               -- tail
      FROM (SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' AS txt  -- use
            UNION ALL                  -- your
            SELECT 'm,n,o') some_data  -- table instead
     WHERE coalesce(txt, '') <> ''
    UNION
    SELECT CASE WHEN locate(',', tail) > 0
                THEN substring(tail, 1, locate(',', tail) - 1)
                ELSE tail
           END,
           CASE WHEN locate(',', tail) > 0
                THEN substring(tail, locate(',', tail) + 1)
                ELSE null
           END
      FROM list
     WHERE tail IS NOT NULL
  )
  SELECT * FROM list) splitted;
```

results in

| pos | head |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | m |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | n |
| 5 | c |
| 6 | o |
| 7 | d |
| 8 | e |

From that, it should be easy to adapt the query to your needs.